# show/hide a download button depending on if the user is on ios

Tags: php, javascript, html, ios

i have this to see if the user is on ios

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Mac OS X/i)) {

        }
```

but how can i hide this

```
<div style="text-align: center;"><a href="http://db.tt/b6ecH2Dh" id="down"><img src="img/download.gif"/></div>
```

if the not on an ios device?

Comment: It seems like you're not detecting iOS, you're detecting Mac OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't know the logic behind this but hope this will work for you with jquery:

```
$('div').parent('#down').css({'display':'none'});
```

hope this will work..

Comment: sorry its a great answer but i want it to hide the div if it ISNT an ios device sorry

Comment: as i understand that you want to hide the div if isn't as ios device then add 'else' also and in the else your suitable javascript or jquery code.. sorry but i am confusing what you want..

Comment: @lewisdenny if this answer helped you, then you should 1.accept it, 2.upvote it.

Answer (score 2):

define an id for the DIV tag:

```
<div id="someid" style="text-align: center;"><a href="http://db.tt/b6ecH2Dh" id="down"><img src="img/download.gif"/></div>
```

and in JS:

```
document.getElementById("someid").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

(Edited, as ponited)

Comment: Should be `document.getElementById("someid").style.visibility = "hidden"`

Comment: sorry its a great answer but i want it to hide the div if it ISNT an ios device sorry

Comment: @lewisdenny we mentioned here how to hide the div you have created, you can put this code it in your choice of condition.

Answer (score 1):

set css property `display` to `none`

```
document.getElementById("someid").style.display = "none"
```

it works better than `visibility` property as it removes element from rendering completely while `visibility` simply makes it transparent but element still takes up space on your page

if you're using jquery it's even simpler:

```
$('#someid').hide()
// or
$('#someid').css({'display': 'none'})
```

plus with jquery you can wrap it in onload hook ultra easy:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if(!/ios check here/) {
    $('#someid').hide()
  }
})
```

Comment: sorry its a great answer but i want it to hide the div if it ISNT an ios device sorry

Comment: that's why there is exclamation mark in `if` statement. `if(!navigator.userAgent.match(/Mac OS X/i))`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide it completely, try this:

```
<?php if(!preg_match("/(Mac OS X)/i",$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])){ ?>
        <div>Content to hide from Mac OS X users</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use this:

http://detectmobilebrowsers.mobi/

With this you can for example add speclial class to  tag and use this for other porpuses.